# unable to connect to docker nginx container from host

Tags: docker

centos 7.8

docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name nginxtest nginx

docker ps
CONTAINER ID IMAGE PORTS                NAMES
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx       nginx 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp nginxtest

curl localhost:8080
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

netstat -tulpn
tcp6 0 0 :::8080 :::* LISTEN 13467/docker-proxy

Is there any other way to check what went wrong?

Comment: I tried to reproduce and my docker is listening on ipv4, and not ipv6. My netstat output looks like this: `tcp LISTEN 0      128  *:8080   *:* `

Comment: On my other server, docker listen on ipv6 and also works fine

Comment: Are you using any VM for docker machine (VirtualBox/...)? If yes, please try access port using IP assigned to your VM.

Answer (score 0):

restart server, and problem solved.